# Entity object to Data Transfer Object (DTO) in Spring React

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have Order Model

```
@Document(collection="order")
public class Order {
  @Id
  String id;

  String desc;

  String orgId;
}
```

And each OrgId is associated with Organization Object

```
@Document(collection="organization")
public class Organization {

    @Id
    String id;

    String desc;

    String ownerEmail;
}
```

My DTO for Order is

```
public class OrderDTO {

    String id;

    String desc;

    Organization org;

}
```

I wanted to return Flux and Mono for OrderDTO in Spring react.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("orders")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
  private OrderService service;

    @Autowired
  private OrganizationService orgService;

    @GetMapping
    public Flux<OrderDTO> findAll() {
        return service.findAll(); // wanted step for Flux<Order> to Flux<OrderDTO>
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<OrderDTO> findOne(@PathVariable String id) {
        return service.findOne(id); // wanted step for Mono<Order> to Mono<OrderDTO>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to sort out your thoughts & steps .

1. **Creating Models `Order` & `Organization`**
2. **Creating the Repository for each model according to DB implementation**, Make your `OrderRepository` & `OrganizationRepository` `extends` for `ReactiveMongoRepository` or `ReactiveCrudRepository`

   ```
   import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

   @Repository
   public interface OrderRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Order, String> {
      // Spring Boot automatically add  an implementation of this interface called SimpleOrderRepository at runtime.

     // So you get all the CRUD methods on the Document readily available to you without needing to write any code. Following are some of the methods available from SimpleReactiveMongoRepository -

     // reactor.core.publisher.Flux<T>  findAll(); 
     // reactor.core.publisher.Mono<T>  findById(ID id); 
     // <S extends T> reactor.core.publisher.Mono<S>  save(S entity); 
     // reactor.core.publisher.Mono<Void>   delete(T entity);

     // Notice that all the methods are asynchronous and return a publisher in the form of a Flux or a Mono type.
   }

   @Repository
   public interface OrganizationRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Organization, String> {

   }
   ```
3. **Creating the Controller Endpoints**

   ```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("orders")
   public class OrderController {

   @Autowired
   private OrderRepository orderRepository;

   @GetMapping
   public Flux<Order> getAllOrders() {
       return orderRepository.findAll();
   }

   @PostMapping
   public Mono<Tweet> createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Order order) {
       return orderRepository.save(order);
   }

   @GetMapping("{id}")
   public Mono<ResponseEntity<Order>> getOrderById(@PathVariable(value = "id") String orderId) {
       return orderRepository.findById(orderId)
               .map(savedOrder -> ResponseEntity.ok(savedOrder))
               .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
   }

   @PutMapping("{id}")
   public Mono<ResponseEntity<Order>> updateTweet(@PathVariable(value = "id") String orderId,
                                                  @Valid @RequestBody Order order) {
       return orderRepository.findById(orderId)
               .flatMap(existingOrder -> {
                   existingOrder.setDesc(order.getDesc());
                   return orderRepository.save(existingOrder);
               })
               .map(updatedOrder -> new ResponseEntity<>(updatedOrder, HttpStatus.OK))
               .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
   }

   @DeleteMapping("{id}")
   public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> deleteOrder(@PathVariable(value = "id") String orderId) {

       return orderRepository.findById(orderId)
               .flatMap(existingOrder ->
                       orderRepository.delete(existingOrder)
                           .then(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK)))
               )
               .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
   }

   // Orders are Sent to the client as Server Sent Events
   @GetMapping(value = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
   public Flux<Order> streamAllOrders() {
       return orderRepository.findAll();
   }
   }
   ```

**Check out [example](https://www.callicoder.com/reactive-rest-apis-spring-webflux-reactive-mongo/) && [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html) for more explanation.**

Comment: Thanks @khaled-lela. Though, I don't think so you got idea. I have created an hypothesis of what exactly I wanted. Somehow I wanted DTO of Mongo Object which I cannot see in you answer. Whatever you mentioned in your code I have that already, just do not find it necessary to mention in my question.

Comment: @SumitRamteke  *As mentioned on my answer* Spring Boot automatically add  an implementation for CRUD. you will need to put your need to write your implementation if you need to make special functions.